# How to call another number when the first one is not responding using AWS connect start_outbound_voice_contact API?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-connect

I have code to call a number using AWS connect start_outbound_voice_contact API as below:

```
import boto3

boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='infra')

client = boto3.client('connect')

response = client.start_outbound_voice_contact(
    DestinationPhoneNumber='XXX',
    ContactFlowId='YYYYY',
    InstanceId='ZZZZZ',
    QueueId='LLLLL',
    Attributes={
        'Attr1':'KKKKK'
    }
)

print response
```

It is working very well. However, when the number does not respond to the call, I want AWS connect service to call another number that I specified. How can I do that using start_outbound_voice_contact API or other AWS connect features such queues, contact flows etc. in the AWS connect dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make a single outbound API call that will use multiple destinations numbers. You would have to control the outbound destinations with the dialing application that is making the API call to Connect, ending the original outbound contact request when you find it unresponsive and then initiating another start outbound contact call with the secondary number.

Comment: Thank you. I come to this point also. Are we able to understand that the opponent has not answered the call via the API?

Comment: You would need to use contact trace records to determine the disposition of the contact initiated by the API call. There is no way to query in real time. This means you would have to initiate the call to the first number, watch CTR steam, and then initiate a call to the second number of CTR of the first call showed no connection time.

Comment: @SerkanYıldırım. Can you help me please? Where are you attaching the above code ? Is it attached to a web application. How does your contact flow looks like ?Thanks

Comment: Hi @Judi, you can find the code here: https://github.com/sekobey/python-scripts/blob/master/call_using_aws_connect.py

And, you can find how I made it in here: https://medium.com/@serkanyldrm_5711/how-to-call-a-number-programmatically-using-amazon-connect-service-api-d6d89889b7dc